# Optimum betting strategy guaranteeing rate of return

Tags: distributions, expected-value, games

A man likes to bet on football matches. He wants to systematise his betting so that he can sleep better at night. His ratio of correct bets to all bets he has made is $r$. He wants to develop a system to multiply the money in his piggy bet bank by $x > 1$ each day.

He wants to make exactly $k$ bets per day, as he only has so much concentration, and he wants to maintain his correctness ratio $r$. Each bet he will make under this scheme has minimum odds (decimal) $b > 1$. That is, the man pays a wager of $w$ to a bookmaker, and receives at least $bw$ in return if his bet is correct. If his bet in incorrect, he receives nothing.

#### Parameters

- $r$ is the ratio of correct bets to all bets.
- $x$ is his desired daily rate of return.
- $b$ is the minimum decimal odds over all bets he will make.
- $k$ is the exact number of bets he wants to make each day.

#### Task

Given the above parameters, what proportion $P$ of his piggy bet bank should he set aside each day to divide as separate wagers for each of the $k$ bets he makes each day to ensure that the money in the piggy bet bank multiplies by at least $x$ on average each day?

I am not sure how to approach this problem. I don't see any of the more typical distributions being involved here. It isn't a binomial deal, as the winnings from the previous day are used for the winnings for the next day. I imagine that a recursive relation may be involved, but I am not sure how to work it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this question just a variation on the kelly criterion?

Comment: That is a new one. It definitely seems so. I suppose we can then simply divide the recommended fraction over $k$? Would you like to add that as an answer?

Comment: On further thought maybe it isn't that simple.

Comment: It seems that my question has been answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2358037/kelly-criterion-for-simultaneous-independent-bets. @RulesOfTheGame Thanks for the suggestion.